# If click outside of element, then toggle

Tags: jquery

In my menu, a user clicks on the link and list appears via `.addClass( "show-nav" )`.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/1/) with JS code:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {

        var hasClass;
        hasClass = jQuery(this).next().hasClass( "show-nav" );

        jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');

        if (hasClass === false) {
            jQuery(this).next().addClass( "show-nav" );
        }

    }
});
```

The problem is: I wish to remove the class `show-nav` if a user clicks **outside** of the div with class `show-nav`. **How can this be achieved?**

I have seen examples of `e.target` div ID but not class, particularly not a situation like this.

Comment: Going to bounty this 50 point in 2 days when eligible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the usual solution:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").click(function(){
    var hasClass;
    hasClass = jQuery(this).next().hasClass( "show-nav" );

    jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');

    if (hasClass === false) {
        jQuery(this).next().addClass( "show-nav" );
    }
    return false;
});
$('.hidden').click(function(){
   // you probably have something else here, it's a menu right ?
   return false;
});

$(window).click(function(){
    jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rueda51v/)

The idea is

1. to return false from the event handler to prevent propagation (you should do it in most event handlers)
2. to handle the click event on `window` to remove the class

A variant to this common pattern is to add the binding on `window` when you show the menu, and to remove it when you close it. It's a little more satisfying if you don't often have this menu displayed.

Comment: Interesting. Will this click work on touch screens (mobile/tablets)?

Comment: Also, what about performance? Isn't this listening to every single click on the page...?

Comment: Clicking on the yellow area should not close it, I guess.

Comment: @GaryWoods this really really doesn't matter. Even if it took one ms (which it doesn't), it's only on clicks...

Comment: @dfsq I edited to make it clearer how to handle that

Comment: @GaryWoods - There's really no way to catch a click anywhere in the document without listening for clicks anywhere in the document. There's no magic *"element wasn't clicked"* selector, one has to check every click anyway. Using something like `$("*:not(.show-nav)")` is a lot worse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to determine whether if your approach or adeneo approach is better as both achieve the same results via different route. What would you suggest? For the record, my menu has around 10 different drop down menu links using this code...

Answer (score 2):

Bind to the document, and check wether or not the anchor was clicked, something inside the shown element was clicked, or if the click was outside

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var nav    = $(e.target).closest('.nav-js-trigger');
    var hidden = $(e.target).closest('.show-nav')

    if ( nav.length > 0 ) {
        $('.show-nav').not( nav.next().toggleClass('show-nav') ).removeClass('show-nav');
    } else if ( hidden.length === 0 ) {
        $('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ghLn4nmL/11/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to determine whether if your approach or @dystroy's approach is better as both achieve the same results via different route. What would you suggest? For the record, my menu has around 10 different drop down menu links using this code...

Comment: Just tested this and it works well. It only has only issue. I have several menu links that add the 'show-nav' class. When clicking on two different ones, it will allow both to be opened. My original code hides the old one before opening the new one. Is there anyway we can implement this behaviour with your code?

Comment: Excellent, works great. Unfortunately, the clicking outside of the div doesn't seem to work on touch screen. I tried changing it to: jQuery(document).on('click touch', function(e) { -- but it still did not detect the touch outside of div. I also tried 'touchend'. Do you know why it's not working?

Comment: More specifically on iPad or apple mobile devices. It works using 'click touch' on android browser.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this will do the trick:

```
jQuery(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").next().is(e.target)) {
        jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").next().removeClass("show-nav");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/5/

Hope this helps!

What @dystroy is suggesting as a fix will remove the class even when clicking inside the menu. My answer will allow the user to click inside the menu with out it closing.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` to differentiate the element you clicked on and the rest.

`e.currentTarget` will be `#menu` in the following case.

**NB**: avoid to attach event handler inside `each`. Select the elements you are interested in and bind your `click` event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/9/

```
jQuery("#menu").click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target); //depends on the element you clicked on
    var isLink = $target.is('a.nav-js-trigger');
    if(isLink) {
        if(!$target.next('.hidden').is('.show-nav')) {
          $target.next('.hidden').addClass('show-nav').show();      
        }
    } else {
        //you click inside #menu but not on a.nav-js-trigger
        $(e.currentTarget).find('.hidden').hide().removeClass('show-nav'); //currentTarget = #menu
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to determine whether if your approach or dystroy and adeneo approach is better as both achieve the same results via different route. What would you suggest? For the record, my menu has around 10 different drop down menu links using this code...

Comment: I think this is a matter of taste. My approach illustrated one usage of target and currentTarget, which are convenient if you can fallback on.

Answer (score 0):

My way — http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/3zc5yt2e/1/:

```
var $trigger = $('.nav-js-trigger');
var $hidden = $trigger.next();
var $all = $trigger.add($hidden);

$trigger.on('click', function() {
    $hidden.toggleClass('show-nav');
});

$(document.body).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest($all).length) {
        $hidden.removeClass('show-nav');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will grab each element as a trigger except the one you don't want to be clickable:

```js
// for all elements...
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.show-nav').hide();  // hide the nav
});

// for the show-nav element
$('.show-nav').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); //  prevent the default nav-closing action
  alert('inside the box');  // alert the inside click
});

// if you click on the button
$('.button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the default nav-closing action
  $('.show-nav').show();  // re-open the nav
  });
```

```css
.show-nav {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-nav">Hello</div>
<br>
<button class="button" type="button">Reopen Nav</button>
```

For brevity:

```
$('html').click(function() {
  $('.show-nav').hide();
});
$('.show-nav').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('inside the box');
});
$('.button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.show-nav').show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'not' option of jquery:

```
$('html').not('.show-nav').click(function() {
    // your function here
}
```